# How to take screenshots of my chrome client using java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that whenever I run it, it takes a screenshot of Google Chrome.  So far, I have figured out how to have it take a screenshot and write it to a file.  However, this is just a screenshot of the entire screen. I'd like to take a screenshot of chrome, even if it is just running in the background.  Also, I'd like to be able to re-size Google Chrome and run the program to get images with the same dimensions as Google Chrome.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class ProgramDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle windowScreen = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        try {
            BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(windowScreen);
            ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File("screenshot.png"));
        } catch (AWTException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use image processing/recognition and recognize a distinctive symbol in your browser.

The other way is to go to the operating system and get the attributes where the window is etc

The third approach is to go with your mouse and check the coordinates/and size "ah now its there" and enter the coordinates into your program, "ah now its there..."

In effect you need the upper left coordinates and the size - any way you can get it

You can put up another question depending on which way you want